# Unable to get input from user in shell script which is called by git hook pre-push script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, githooks

I am running a shell script from another shell script which is a `git-hook pre-push`.

This is the content of .git/hooks/pre-push:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

protected_branch='master'
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $current_branch ]; then
    sh test.sh
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "Error"
        exit 1
    fi
else
    exit 0
fi
```

This is the content of test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
run_base=1
    run_test () {
        read -p "enter varname: " varname
        echo $varname
    }
time {
        if [ "$run_base" = "0" ] ; then 
            echo "skipped"
        else 
            time { run_test ; }
            echo "run_test done";
        fi
}
```

If I run `pre-push` script directly, then it works fine, but it doesn't work when I execute `git push origin master` and `pre-push` gets triggered automatically.

`read` in test.sh is not being executed when I trigger the `pre-push` hook script. Do I need to do anything specific in order to execute `read` in `test.sh` which is called from `pre-push`?

Answer (score 0):

I just test it on my computer and it works perfectly, 
isoto@hal9014-2 ~/w/test> ./pre-push
enter varname: asd
asd

real    0m1.361s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
run_test done

real    0m1.361s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

So, the only thing that I did was to add executable permissions, chmod +x *
And also I put both scripts in the same directory, besides everything should work.

Comment: If I execute pre-push script directly, then I do not see any issue, I see this issue when I execute `git push origin master` which triggers pre-push script automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I had to add `< /dev/tty` at the end of `read`:

```
read -p "enter varname: " varname < /dev/tty
echo $varname
```